# ASP.NET error: IsBadPath() Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting an {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} exception randomly (it seems random) on a server. I can reproduce the exception using fiddler and my local machine by passing in no header data.

The stack trace is

```
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.IsBadPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.TryParseRequest()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(Object acceptedSocket)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

any ideas? I can't get to the problematic code because No source available or symbols have not been loaded'.

**ASP.NET 3.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the unhandled leftovers from `Response.Redirect` call.

Comment: the code is using Response.Redirect(url, false) what do you suggest?

Comment: the problem was from user code but the error handler was still doing a redirect.

Comment: wrap the Response.Redirect(..) call in try{ ...} catch(ThreadAbortException taex) {} block

Answer (score 0):

In my case this same problem happened because of invalid (too many?) cookies.  I cleared the cookies and the problem went away.